# How can I get a message that says when you can unplug a usb stick safely?

Tags: usb, mount, hardware, umount, eject

I have a memory stick. when data is being written, the led flashes. I right click, and select eject, the led will flash and when it stops I will unplug it.
Other memory sticks, do not have LEDs, how can I be certain the OS is done with the memory device, before unplugging it? Theres no pop-up message I have ever seen for that.

I am using the Desktop Environment Mate 1.12.1.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the USB stick on the launcher and **when its icon disappears it's safe to unplug it**...

#### No annoying pop-up needed/nor given!

You do get a notification when you eject or safely remove *an external hard drive, **but not for USB sticks.***

Comment: You do get a notification when you **eject** or **safely remove** am external hard drive, but not for USBs.

Comment: **j0h**:  Good enough???  **;-)** @user68186: that comment by itself is good enough to receive and upvote or 2-3.  Will do that elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks! I was playing with external hard drives, gparted and screenshots. So it was easy to test.

Comment: Hi @Fabby, I use Ubuntu Mate, although I looked at a friends computer where she is using Unity, and I do see the thing you're talking about.